# How can i put a pointer on a map of my entered address. Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show a pointer on a map after entering address. What would be best solution ? Couldn't find any tutorials on this problem. I found a code to get latitude and longitude, what to do next ?

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
    if (address == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address location = address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                      (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

     return p1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addmarker() function will help you to achieve this

```
 myMap.addMarker(new   MarkerOptions().position(yourLatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.yourmarkericon)));
```

where myMap is the Object of GoogleMap and yourLatlng is Latlng Where you want to add marker and yourmarkericon is icon which you want to display on map. Use blow link for more information

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html

Comment: this method requires  .positon(LatLng) i have a GeoPoint. So i need to  convert it ?

Comment: position(new LatLng(current_lat, current_long))